# fwrite() send of 40 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a project using codeigniter framework

there i have some code like below

```
fwrite($this->_smtp_connect, $data . $this->newline))
```

$data contains the data to be sent through email

But I am getting the error

> Severity: Notice  --> fwrite(): send of 40 bytes failed with **errno=32** Broken pipe

How to solve this?

Comment: You are sending mail and connection to server dropped. Does it happen every time? (If you are not sending mail, you should also clarify so.)

Comment: Hi @Swathi S, actually are you sending mail using smtp ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694351/error-while-sending-an-email-with-codeigniter) will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cpanel for your website smtp restrictions are problem and cause this error.

SMTP Restrictions

This feature prevents users from bypassing the mail server to send mail, a common practice used by spammers. It will allow only the MTA, mailman, and root to connect to remote SMTP servers.

This control is also adjustable in Tweak Settings.

This setting has been updated.

The SMTP restriction is disabled.