# Unable to send emails SMPT errors in codigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, codeigniter-3

This is my code, I tried smtp_port 587,465, and 25 too. But I'm unable to send an email. And my website is not SSL so I avoid **ssl://smtp.googlemail.com** instead of I use **smtp.googlemail.com** and I also tried with **ssl://smtp.googlemail.com**

```
public function email()
{
     $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '******',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('uvizag@gmail.com', 'Vizag updates');
    $this->email->to('siddharthaesunuri@gmail.com'); 
    $this->email->subject('Activation link...! Vizag updates');
    $msg = "your activation link <a href='base_url'>click here</a>";
    $this->email->message($msg);
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();    
}
```

How can I solve this ? can you help me please I appreciate your valuable answer

[Please click to show my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLNMC.png)

**or**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2172

Backtrace:
```

Comment: Your image is very small cannot read errors.

Comment: Now you can able to see, or use zoom in my image

Comment: I answered this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694351/error-while-sending-an-email-with-codeigniter/49253437#49253437

Answer (score 2):

When I got that error something with my authentication was wrong.

Make sure to disable two step verification or enable access for less secure apps.

[This tutorial](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-gmail-smtp/) did the trick for me.

Hope it helps

Comment: @Siddhu have you tried setting 'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl' ?

Comment: Yes, I tried @jonas. after that, I get this warning                                      Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Answer (score 1):

finally, I solved

we need to give google access permissions
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

```
public function send()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '****@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '***',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('uvizag@gmail.com', 'admin');
    $this->email->to('siddharthaesunuri@gmail.com, siddhu.php@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Registration Verification:');
    $message = "Thanks for signing up! Your account has been created...!";
    $this->email->message($message);
    if ( ! $this->email->send()) {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
```