# CodeIgniter email throws error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I cannot send mail using CodeIgniter. It displays the following error.

`fwrite(): send of 28 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

This my settings in **email.php** library

```
public $useragent   = 'CodeIgniter';
public $mailpath    = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'; // Sendmail path
public $protocol    = 'smtp';       // mail/sendmail/smtp
public $smtp_host   = 'smtp.mailhostbox.com';
public $smtp_user   = 'xxx@xx.in';
public $smtp_pass   = 'xxxxxx';
public $smtp_port   = 25;
public $smtp_timeout    = 5;
public $smtp_keepalive  = FALSE;
public $smtp_crypto = '';
public $newline     = "\r\n";
```

I could send email till yesterday. But from today morning, it shows this error.
**UPDATE :** 
I have changed my host to `gmail` , but still not working. The following are the changes I made

```
public $useragent   = 'CodeIgniter';
public $mailpath    = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'; // Sendmail path
public $protocol    = 'smtp';       // mail/sendmail/smtp
public $smtp_host   = 'smtp.gmail.com';
public $smtp_user   = 'noreply.xxx@gmail.com';
public $smtp_pass   = 'xxxxxx';
public $smtp_port   = 465;
public $smtp_timeout    = 5;
public $smtp_keepalive  = FALSE;
public $smtp_crypto = 'ssl';
public $newline     = "\r\n";
```

But it shows error as
`Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465:465 (Failed to parse address "smtp.gmail.com:465:465")`

I changed the port from 465 to 587 as follows

```
public $smtp_port   = 587;
public $smtp_crypto = 'tls';
```

But I got this error

`Message: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`

I couldn't understand what is the real issue, because it throws errors in every possible conditions

Comment: Change `$smtp_port` value to `465`

Comment: i changed port to `465` but i get some other error as `fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.mailhostbox.com:465 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )`

Comment: I hope you have checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694351/error-while-sending-an-email-with-codeigniter

Comment: I have checked and suggestions listed there didn't work for me

Comment: did you  initialise the config ?

Comment: I think he pasted the default settings from the Email library file itself. So it should be initialized? Also, did you change anything in your code between the working and not working state? It seems like something might have changed on the SMTP server side.

Comment: @Clemenz Nothing chenged. I checked it with my network administrator.

Comment: please check my update

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the config.[see here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

For Example

```
function send_email($attributes) {

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'host';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@smtp.com';
        $config['smtp_from_name'] = 'FROM NAME';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'XXX';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';                       

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from($config['smtp_user'], $config['smtp_from_name']);
        $this->email->to($attributes['to']);
        $this->email->cc($attributes['cc']);
        $this->email->bcc($attributes['cc']);
        $this->email->subject($attributes['subject']);

        $this->email->message($attributes['message']);

        if($this->email->send()) {
            return true;        
        } else {
            return false;
        }       

}
```

Comment: `$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");` is redundant to this line: `$config['newline'] = "\r\n";` I would prefer the second line, as you set all the other parameters this way.

Comment: i have already set all these parameters in`email library`. And load this file using `auotoload.php`