# Send email using laravel in register system

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to build a login/register system in Laravel. I created all the views and controllers autogenerated (Laravel can do this for you with some commands).

The logic of login + register works fine but when I tried to do email verification after I setup everything in .env when I try to register and send email verification I get this error :

```
fwrite(): send of 18 bytes failed with errno=10054 Une connexion existante a d� �tre ferm�e par l�h�te distant
```

I am using "mailtrap" which gives u like a fake email to test with it.

This is my .env configuration
'''

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME= "username that i have in my mailtrap inbox"
MAIL_PASSWORD= "password that i have in my mailtrap inbox"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION= NULL
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

PS. I am following a tutorial on youtube and I did the same steps as him and it works fine for him. I am using Laravel 7. Thank you very much.

Comment: check out this thread (not laravel but similar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694351/error-while-sending-an-email-with-codeigniter   it looks like a config on your server stopping smtp

Comment: thanks i tried the solutions mentioned in the link but none worked for me ..

Comment: ps : sometimes the error is : "expected response 250 but got empty"

Comment: be sure to run php artisan config:cache when making config / env changes.
```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=yourusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```
change your from address to example.com  (not gmail) just to verify that isn't an issue. get rid of this MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}" for now.

Comment: @Cameron .. Thank you sir for your good and well explained answer .. it worked for me without changing "gmail".